# How can I customize the report .xml output to contain info about JUnit suite’s test classes?

Tags: maven, testng, jira-zephyr

Hope you are doing well.
I have a quick question please  if someone can help me.
In my case i can publish the result of my test on Zephyr for JIRA cloud. But I have in the summary field of my testcases the name of the package like (`com.testcases.classname.methodname`).
 How can we do that in order to have some description in that field instead of the name of the package please?

For example, if I wanted the `.xml` output file to look like this:

`<testcase name="Test case name" classname="my description or summury like : test of my software XXXX" time="xxxx"/>`

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: <testcase name="TestClass1.testHandleCacheOne" classname="webdriver.test.SuiteOne" time="14.759"/>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you want to add something to your question, there's an _edit_ link (that doesn't look like one :) below your question's tags.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICS from the doc of [surefire:test](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) and [TestNG's annotations](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) (though it has `@Test.description` but if this is not printed to result `.xml`) this is not going to work without self-written:

- mapping of `testcase.name` → *your test case name*
- mapping of `testcase.classname` →  *your description or summary*
- string replacement according to the mappings

You could develop a [custom Maven plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) with `test` as its [default phase](https://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html#The_Descriptor_and_Annotations) for this. Another option is to use the the [Exec Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to perform string replacement with a tool like [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) or [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).

Comment: thank you for tour answer, i tried to add some description to my test methode like this : @Test(testName="My test case name",description="My test case description") but that dosn't printed in my xml output TEST-TestSuite.xml. can you please provide me an sample exemple to do that

Comment: @mustaphaousikis There is an example how to write an own plugin on the third page I linked. See also the last sentence update to my question.